# Insert a whitespace in normal mode (used in insert mode)

Tags: vim, whitespace

Based on the idea of [quick command in insert mode](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Quick_command_in_insert_mode) I want to insert my OS clipboard when I am in the insert mode. To make that happen as I want, I have to add a whitespace in the `inoremap` call, but I do not know how?

This is done with

```
inoremap VV <Esc>"+gP
```

Using this:

- "vim" is in the OS clipboard
- Typing in insert mode "work smart with VV"

leads to the result

```
work smart withvim
```

What I want is a whitespace between with and vim

```
work smart with vim
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is caused by the `P` in `"+gP` *and* by the fact that leaving insert mode moves the cursor one character to the left, on the `<space>`.

`P` pastes *before* the cursor so your mapping pastes *before* the `<space>`. Changing the `P` to `p` should "fix" your problem, in a superficial way.

Here is a more solid alternative that inserts the content of the clipboard register right after the cursor *without leaving insert mode*:

```
inoremap VV <C-r>+
```

Well… what about simply using `<C-r>+`?

---

Working around a side effect (here, pasting after the cursor) is not the same as avoiding that side effect (here, not leaving insert mode to begin with). Guess which one is the right approach? ;-)

Comment: `inoremap VV <C-r>+` is the solution for me, as my solution had the drawback that I ended up in the normal mode after pasting. The shortcut `<C-r>+` is finger acrobatic, VV is more convenient in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
inoremap VV <Esc>"+gp
```

`P` places the clipboard before cursor, `p` after cursor.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1.**

```
   inoremap VV <C-R><C-o>+
```

`Ctrl-R` tells vim to insert the contents of a register, and `+` is the OS clipboard register.  It inserts the clipboard contents as if you typed them.  The additional `<c-o>` makes the register contents get inserted literally, so that things like `<esc>` or `^H` (backspace) aren't interpreted like you typed them, but are inserted as text.

**Option 2.**

```
   inoremap VV <C-o>"+gp
```

`C-o` tells vim to go to normal mode for just one command, so you don't need to add `<Esc>` at start, or `i` at the end.